# Tesselation in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm not getting the expected filling when tessellating some self-intersecting polygons.

For example using some simple sample code demonstrating OpenGL tessellation that can be [downloaded](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/files/tessellation.zip) from [here](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_tessellation.html)

and making a couple of very simple modifications:
firstly, at line 272 change the x & y coords of the self-intersection polygon to ...

```
GLdouble star[5][6] = { {1.0, 2.0, 0,  1, 0, 0},       // 0: x,y,z,r,g,b
                        {0.0, 2.0, 0,  0, 1, 0},       // 1:
                        {3.0, 0.0, 0,  1, 0, 1},       // 2:
                        {0.0, 4.0, 0,  1, 1, 0},       // 3:
                        {-1.0, 0.0, 0,  0, 0, 1} };    // 4:
```

and at line 296, change the filling rule to EvenOdd...

```
gluTessProperty(tess, GLU_TESS_WINDING_RULE, GLU_TESS_WINDING_ODD);
```

and compile and run and I get the following image which shows what I don't believe is the correct filling. (I'm not seeing the triangular hole in the third object.)
[image]

Here's what the polygon without filling looks like ...
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment Christian, but suggesting an alternative would be even more helpful.

Comment: @AngusJohnson You can try LibTess2 which is modern remake of GLU tessellator.Btw,thanks for your PolygonClipper lib!Also,did you try such a type of self-intersection on other shapes?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion re LibTess2 MichaelIV. And thanks for your encouragement re Clipper too. It is because of Clipper, and creating simple demo apps for it using a variety of graphic libraries, that I'm battling with GLU Tessellation. Yes I've tried other self-intersecting shapes and it **mostly** seems to work as expected.

Comment: @AngusJohnson Great,please let us know here if LibTess2 worked for you!

Comment: I think you should try to use modern OpenGL tesselation not glu stuff.

Comment: @AngusJohnson were you able to resolve this issue? I can reproduce the problem but cannot think of any root causes.